# Send Mail from Windows Machine using Shell ( from Git bash)

Tags: linux, windows, shell, unix, smtp

I have migrated code from Unix OS to Windows. But was stuck in Mail Service from Windows to Users Mail ID.
This Service "**/usr/sbin/sendmail**" was available in Linux OS BUT Dont know how it works in Windows.
Please help to setup sendmail in WIndows. and I am using Git bash to run shell script in Azure Windows Machine.

```
cat - $HOME/missJobMailer.txt <<EOF | /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -t
From: ${MAILFROM}
To: ${MAILTO}
Subject: $SUBJECT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
MIME-Version: 1.0
EOF
```

Edit( Updated)

I am using below command to store string in body variable

```
 $body= Get-Content -Path C:\Users\xyz\Documents\failed_cloud_alert\missJobMailer.txt | Out-String 

Send-MailMessage -To mailid  -From  maild -Subject "TEST"
    -Body $body -SmtpServer $server
```

My File has HTML Format. It is sending whole text on mail, not HTML Format. Please help to it can be resolved from powershell

```
</head><body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#2e86c1">
<p style="font-size:15px;">
<font color="#2e86c1">
Hi Team, <br /> <br />

Below are the Failed jobs. Please take necessary action. <br />
</font>
 
</p> <br />
<table border="1">
```

Comment: Do we need smtp server to sent mail from Powershell ? If we need, can you please tell how to check SMTP Server details from windows machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git bash is a minimal packaging of common Linux utilities.  It isn’t a full replacement for a Linux system (as you’re discovering).

It looks like if powershell is installed on your windows machine, the commandlet “send-mailmessage” does what you need. Assuming you can restructure your code a bit to call it properly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.1

Alternatively, you could install the Windows Subsystem for Linux, which does give a full version of Linux to run on windows. But then you would have to configure sendmail to talk to your smtp server, which isn’t necessarily trivial.

Comment: Nicolas, Do we need smtp server to sent mail from Powershell ? If we need, can you please tell how to check SMTP Server details from windows machine?

Comment: Yes you will, and that’s a somewhat complicated question. Depends on your domain name for one thing. For example, If sending from a gmail account you would use gmail smtp servers.  Here’s a discussion of how to do it. But you will need a general understanding of smtp to follow the discussion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278447/how-to-setup-an-smtp-server-in-azure#58279519

Comment: I got my smtp server. telnet smtp_server 25 is also working.

Comment: Nicholas, I have updated my question. Facing issue with HTML VS TXT Format. Can you please suggest?

Comment: No Problem, we need to add --BodyAsHtml only. Thanks